# Android Spinner Option Value Just like Select Tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Is it Possible I can create a spinner with options and values.

```
<select name=test>
<option value="1">Baran</option>
<option value="2">Khan</option>
</select>
```

with the spinner XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="test">
    <item Value="1">Baran</item>
    <item value="2">Khan</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

How can I accomplish such target. As I need to pass Ids to the Server.

Comment: didn't get your concept? what you want ?

Comment: I want to have functionality just like a select tag in HTML 5 on the Android application.

Comment: i dont know what is that. but like if i have 2 value in spinner first is **one** and **two** then i select one then what action you want to do ?

Comment: Basically What I want to do, If i select one it should post 12 and when i select two it should post 15 to the server. All Items will be populated dynamically...

Comment: okay.got it. you wait post the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manage two list and both are dynamic as you want.

**Step to achieve :**

- `Create` two `ArrayList<String>`.Depend on your data type here i make as String Array.
- `Add value` to ArrayList.
- `Create custom adapter` and pass two list adapter in that and get value according that.
- `Add list` to Spinner Adapter. Get the index or position of
  the Spinner.
- Follow `same index to get value from second list value`.
- `Send that value to server`.
- Task over

[See Demo Example that will Guide you to make easy.](http://ashvinhinsu.blogspot.in/2012/04/custom-spinner-example.html)

Enjoy !!!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best but one approach would be to create another string array with the ids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="test">
    <item Value="1">Baran</item>
    <item value="2">Khan</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="testIDS">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Now when item `i` is selected from array `test` you can get the id from item `i` in array `testIDS`.